# Solve a first-order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How can I start to solve this differential equation?

$$ y' = \frac{y}{2y\ln(y)+y-x} $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

You could notice that the equation simplifies if you consider $x$ as a function of $y$. So $$y' = \frac{y}{2y\ln(y)+y-x}$$ becomes $$x'+\frac{x}{y}=1+2\log(y)$$ I am sure that you can take from here.